# Is a PCIe 6 pin to EPS 8 pin adapter reliable?

Tags: power-supply

I am looking at a dual CPU motherboard which requires a 24 pin and two 8 pin power plugs. The power supply I intend to use only has a single EPS 8 pin but it has two PCIe connectors and there are 6 pin PCIe to 8 pin EPS converters. Are they safe to use? The CPUs are 115W TDP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The EPS adapter should be fine by itself.  However, if you put to many amps on one circuit inside the power supply that could cause a problem.  Some modern power supplies have channels or rails to divide the massive amps flowing through them.  Each rail will have a similar amount of the load to make a short circuit less damaging.

So if your power supply is too small or load too many on a single wire then yes it will cause a problem.  If you buy a poor quality power supply then it would overload much easier.